# Chr(10) row match

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm pretty new to VBA and pretty lost. I am currently am looking at excel data that downloads in a specific format where a single row has multiple cells with the Chr(10) or Alt+Enter character. This results in two cells being next to each other on the same row, one with three lines of data, and the next with four lines of data.

I need to find a way to split the paragraphs in a single cell into multiple rows. For example, if one cell has three rows, they should each be in their own respective cell and row. The problem is, there is no clean number because in the same row, one cell will have four line breaks and the next cell will have five line breaks (it's random).

What I'm hoping to do is have VBA examine the entire row, find the cell with the most line breaks and then have the whole row split into multiple rows and cells at the line break according to the cell in the row with the most line breaks. For example, if in a single row, you have a cell with 3 lines and a cell with 4 lines, I need the four lines to be four separate rows and cells, and the 3 lines to be 3 separate rows and cells and then an additional BLANK row and cell underneath because the data still needs to match in number!

This would then need to run through every row on the sheet and make sure all of the rows were split according to the largest value of line breaks in the row ("Alt+Enter" values).

Is there any way to do this?

Here's an example of the before and after

[image]

Comment: `Split(cellValue, vbLf)` will give you an array of values which you can then populate into one cell per value.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full solution, rather a few components you may need/use to build your code. The first `MsgBox` will give you the count of line breaks, which you will need to know to find the max.

The next 3 `MsgBox` will show you how to split, and call, the strings separated by `Chr(10)`

---

```
Sub PartialHelp()

Dim Stringg

MsgBox Len(Range("A1")) - Len(Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Range("A1"), Chr(10), ""))

Stringg = Split(Range("A1"), Chr(10))

MsgBox Stringg(0)
MsgBox Stringg(1)
MsgBox Stringg(2)

End Sub
```

Good luck!

Comment: Not an answer. Should be posted as a comment.